# Email form not working (Php noobie)

Tags: php, contact-form

I just started learning php and my first project was to make a working contact form. I have typed up what I could, but for some reason there appears to be some sort of errors that php is not telling me. I have looked for solutions to the issue on another web forum like phpacademy, and to no avail. I finally came to try out stack overflow, since I have heard great things about this forum. Any help is appreciated, and thanks in advance.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Contact</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css"/>

    <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't websites if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
</head>
<body>


    <?php

    if ($_POST['submit']){


if(!$_POST['firstname']){

$error='<br /> Please Enter your first name';

}

if(!$_POST['lastname']){

$error='<br /> Please Enter your last name';

}

if(!$_POST['email']){

$error='<br /> Please Enter your email address';

}

if(!$_POST['phone']){

$error='<br /> Please Enter your phone number';

}

if(!$_POST['message']){

$error='<br /> Please Enter your message you would like to send';

}

if($_POST['email']!="" and !filter_var($_POST['email'],
FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)){

$error.='<br /> Please enter a valid email address';

}


if($error){
$result='<div class="alert alert-danger"><strong>One or more errors has occurred</strong>'.$error.'</div>';
}

else {
if (mail("casey@caseywoelfle.com", "Potential Client!", "FirstName: " .
$_POST['firstname'] . "

LastName ".$_POST['lastname'] ."

Email: " .$_POST['email'] . "

Phone: ".$_POST['phone']  . "  

Comment: ".$_POST['comment'])) {


$result = '<div class="alert alert-success"><strong>Thank you!</strong>I\'ll be in touch within 2 business days.</div>';

} else {


$result = '<div class="alert alert-danger"> Sorry, there was an error sending your message. Please try again later.</div>';

}

}

}

?>

<nav class="navbar">
    <div class="container-full">
        <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand honey-sb" href="#">CW</a>
        </div>

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li><a class="nLink" href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                <li><a class="nLink" href="about.html">About</a></li>
                <li><a class="nLink" href="portfolio.html">Portfolio</a></li>
                <li><a class="nLink" href="contact.php">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>

<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row contact-sec">

        <div class="col-md-12">
                <form class="form-horizontal" method="post">
                        <div class="well">
                        <h1 class="text-center header">Contact Me</h1>
                            <h3 class="text-center">
                                Do you have a project you would like me to take a look at or maybe you have an idea?<br/>Either
                                way don’t hesitate to send me an email using the contact form or give me a call.
                            </h3>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <span class="col-md-1 col-md-offset-2 text-center"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i></span>
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="InputFirstName" name="firstname" type="text" placeholder="First Name" class="form-control">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <span class="col-md-1 col-md-offset-2 text-center"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i></span>
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="InputLastName" name="lastname" type="text" placeholder="Last Name" class="form-control">
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <span class="col-md-1 col-md-offset-2 text-center"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></i></span>
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="InputEmail" name="email" type="text" placeholder="Email Address" class="form-control">
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <span class="col-md-1 col-md-offset-2 text-center"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-earphone"></i></span>
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="InputPhone" name="phone" type="text" placeholder="Phone" class="form-control">
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <span class="col-md-1 col-md-offset-2 text-center"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></i></span>
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <textarea class="form-control" id="InputMessage" name="message" placeholder="Enter your massage for us here. We will get back to you within 2 business days." rows="7"></textarea>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="well">

                            <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="col-sm-4 col-sm-offset-4 text-center">
                                <button type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Submit</button>
                            </div>
                            </div>

                        </div>
                </form>
    </div>
</div>
</div>




<footer>
    <div class="container-fluid">

        <div class="row" id="f-nav">

            <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3 text-center" id="f-contact">
                <h2 class="footerbolder">Contact</h2>

                <img src="images/ph.png" class="img-responsive" alt=""/>

            </div>

            <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3 text-center" id="f-about">
                <h2 class="footerbolder">About Us</h2>

                <img src="images/ph.png" class="img-responsive" alt=""/>

            </div>

            <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3 text-center" id="f-services">
                <h2 class="footerbolder">Services</h2>

                <img src="images/ph.png" class="img-responsive" alt=""/>

            </div>

            <div class="col-xs-6  col-sm-3 text-center" id="f-follow">
                <h2 class="footerbolder">Follow Me</h2>

                <img src="images/ph.png" class="img-responsive" alt=""/>

            </div>

        </div>

        <div class="row">

            <div class="hidden-xs col-sm-12" id="pp-tos">
                <div class="center-block text-center">
                    <a class="" href="#">Terms of Service</a>
                    <a>|</a>
                    <a class="" href="#">Privacy Policy</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>




    </div>
</footer>





<!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/Fittext/jquery.fittext.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: if all validation rules are passed, your `$error` variable is not defined, so your check `if($error)` would yield `PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: error in [script path, line number]` and NOT return `false` as you expect

Comment: So how would I go about fixing that? I would have to make a $error variable right?

Comment: What is outputted when the form processes?

Comment: The way it was intended to work  it would send the an email with their first name, last name, phone number, and message to the email specified.

Comment: I attempted to turn on errors, but when I put the error reporting snipet in error_reporting(); It spits out nothing. weither I fill out the form or not.

Answer (score 0):

@B-and-P is right, if all your error checking validates, then your error variable is undefined by the time you reach your

```
if($error)
```

statement. To fix this, simply declare your error variable at the top to be null like

```
$error = NULL;
```

that way when you check for it, it is defined and if there is no errors, your script will send your mail.

Answer (score 0):

There is no **action** attribute in your form tag. Example:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" method="post" action="send_form_email.php">
```

cut the PHP script from your code and put it in a separate file. Save as **send_form_email.php**

http://askguyson.com/simple-form-to-email-php-contact-form/

Comment: if action attribute is omitted, the form is submitted to self

Comment: When i use this method the submit button just sends me to a blank page, not the most pretty thing to look at, and it will probably confuse users.